# Can't align the input text with the radio button properly

Tags: html, css, radio-button, vertical-alignment, text-align

HTML

```
<fieldset>
        <label id="radio-buttons">Would you recommand this website?
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="button" class="inline" checked>Yes</input>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="button" class="inline">No</input>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="button" class="inline">Maybe</input>
        </label>
</fieldset>
```

CSS

```css
input{
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1.3em;
}
.inline{
     width: unset;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I tried aligning the radio buttons with the text itself but the buttons end up being a few pixels above the text, I tried everything I could find online and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

> min-height offsets your alignment. You can drop it and it's all good.
> You can also get rid of the vertical-align.

In that case you need to rework the whole thing. Here's a quick fix. And here's more info on how to set it up properly in the future: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  /* optional, for the sake of SO editing */
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <p>Would you recommand this website?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="button" id="yes" checked>
  <label for="yes">Yes</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="button" id="no">
  <label for="no">No</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="button" id="maybe">
  <label for="maybe">Maybe</label><br>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I want them to be under the other, not in line

Comment: added a fix and a link to the mdn documentation

Answer (score 0):

`<Label>` and `<input>` doesn't work this way.

This way clicking on `Yes`, `No` or `Maybe` will effect on their respectives radio boxes.

```css
fieldset {
  width     : fit-content;
  min-width : 20em;
  }
label {
  display : inline-block;
  margin  : .3em 2rem 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend> Would you recommand this website? </legend>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Yes" checked >
    Yes
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="No" >
    No
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Maybe" >
    Maybe
  </label>
</fieldset>
```